# Как сверстать такой элемент полукруга?

Tags: html, css

Собственно нужен такой элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать так, но не получилось, линия полукруга не доходит до нужного момента:

```css
.complex {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.line-box {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: relative;
}
.ico-complex-box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.ico-complex-box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(46deg);
}
.ico-complex-box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 133px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="complex">
  <div class="top-line-box">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="ico-complex-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы это делал с помощью свойства [clip](https://webref.ru/css/clip). Хотя, есть достаточно других инструментов, как, например, SVG или canvas

```css
.complex {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.line-box {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: relative;
}
.ico-complex-box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.ico-complex-box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, 65px, 65px);
}
.ico-complex-box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect(auto, 65px, 65px, auto);
}
```

```html
<section class="complex">
  <div class="top-line-box">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="ico-complex-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот на css:

```css
/* базовые стили */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Общая фигура */
.line-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

/* левая\правая линии фигуры */
.line-box:before,
.line-box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #3962b5;
  bottom: 0%;
}
/* левая линии фигуры */
.line-box:before {  
  left: -9999px;
  right: 100%;
}
/* правая линии фигуры */
.line-box:after {
  right: -9999px;
  left: 100%;
}

/* обертка полукруга в центре фигуры */
.ico-complex-box {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* полукруг в центре фигуры */
.ico-complex-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #3962b5;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
/* обертка Сектора полукруга в центре фигуры */
.ico-complex-box.box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 65px;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
/* Сектор полукруга в центре фигуры */
.ico-complex-box.box-2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 3px solid #3962b5;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}

.ico-complex-box.box-2:before {
  display: none;
} 

.top-line-box{ overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<section class="complex">
  <div class="top-line-box">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="ico-complex-box">

      </div>
      <div class="ico-complex-box box-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```